# How to find all the links to a directory

Tags: directory, hard-link

When I stat a directory I get a listing that tell me there are 5 links to the directory.

```
stat dir
```

My question is how do I get information (names and locations) to all these 5 links?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need `ls` (or `find`).

When you create a directory, its link count starts at 2:

- One for the directory itself
- One for the `.` link inside itself

The other thing that increases the directory's link count is its subdirectories: they all have a `..` entry linking back to their parent, adding one to its link count.

You can't hardlink directories in Linux, so these are the only things that count towards the link count - two plus number of subdirectories.

Comment: Interesting, I never put it together in my head that `.` and `..` are just links.  I've always thought of them as magic dots.