# What is the number between file permission and owner in ls -l command output?

Tags: ls

The output of `ls -l` command yields the following result:

[image]

What is the number field between file permission and owner? i.e. what are those **1, 1, 1, and 2**? I checked the `--help` but that doesn't explain it.

[EDIT] 
I thought it was the number of files in a directory but it isn't. See image. "tempFolder" has 3 files but still show a "2"

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Note: edited after @StephaneChazelas comment**

The first number of the `ls -l` output after the permission block is [the number of hard links](https://linuxaria.com/howto/counting-and-listing-hard-links-on-linux).

It is the same value as the one returned by the `stat` command in "Links".

> This number is the hardlink count of the file, when referring to
> a file, or the number of contained directory entries, when referring
> to a directory.

A **file** typically has a hard link count of 1 but this changes if hard links are made with the `ln` command. See [the Debian Reference manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch01.en.html#_links).

In your example, adding a hard link for tempFile2 will increase its link count:

```
ln -l
ln tempFile2 tempHardLink
ln -l
```

Both *tempFile2* and *tempHardLink* will have a link count of 2.

If you do the same exercise with a symbolic link (`ln -s tempFile2 tempSymLink`), the count value will not increase.

A **directory** will have a minimum count of 2 for `'.'` (link to itself) and for the entry in its parent's directory .

In your example, if you want to increase the link count of *tempFolder*, create a new directory and the number will go up.

```
ls -l tempFolder
mkdir tempFolder/anotherFolder
ls -l tempFolder
```

The link from *anotherFolder/* to *tempFolder/* (which is `..`) will be added to the count.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31073/how-to-find-all-the-links-to-a-directory/31074#31074

Comment: Since it is displayed between the permissions and the ownership, you get the impression it very important, but I never used it. When is it typically needed?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg when file systems were *far less* reliable than they are now and you were working on the file system you developed, and `ls` could spend 2 characters and give you more information, and there was no `stat(1)` command nor `find(1)` nor `fsck`, nor symlinks it was probably far more useful than it is today. It can't be changed without breaking shell scripts whose writers have long past into `/dev/null`; It has been that way since at least 1979.

Comment: May I know what its means for the dingdong.txt having value of 1 ? and what means if the value is 0 ?

Answer (score 13):

On Unix, typically, a file is some entry in a table of files. There are different sorts of files: regular files, devices, symbolic links, doors, pipes, sockets, directories...

The inode number (which you can see in the output of `ls -i`) is the index in that table.

Now, you don't access files by *inode* but by *path*. A *path* is a chain of *directory* entries. You'll notice we're not talking of *folder* but of *directory* here. Because it is what a directory is (think of a phone directory).

A directory is a special kind of file that gives names to a number of inodes. A directory entry is a mapping from a name to an inode.

A given file (an inode) can have more than one name in one directory (just like there can be more than one name at a phone number), and can also have names (entries) in more than one directory. Those are called *links*, also known as *hard links* to distinguish from *soft links* (a slang term for *symbolic link,* which is a special type of file which is a pointer to a path).

A file (inode) keeps track of the number of links (of entries in any directory) that it has, so that when the number reaches 0 (when it is being unlinked from the last directory it was referenced in), it is deallocated.

That's that number (the number of links) that is displayed in the `ls -l` output.

When a non-directory file is created the first time (with the `open` or `creat` (or `bind` or `mknod` for some types of files) system calls), it is done by providing a path to the new file (like `"/a/b"`). What happens then is a new file and inode is allocated and a new entry is added to the directory associated with the `"a"` name in the `"/"` root directory. That's the initial *link* so the link count is one.

More links can be added later on with the `link()` system call (the `ln` command). And links can be removed with the `unlink()` system call (the `rm` command).

You'll notice that the files of type *directory* generally have a number of links greater or equal to 2.

Now, when you create a directory, you're calling the `mkdir()` system call. Something like `mkdir("/a/b")`. What it does then is allocate a new file of type directory. In that new directory, it automatically creates two entries:

- `"."` (*dot* for *directory*). Which is a link to itself. So the link count is now 1.
- `".."` (for *directory*'s *directory*). Which is a link to `"/a"`. So the link count of `"/a"` is incremented by one

Then that new directory is linked to `"/a"` (an entry is added in `"/a"` for it), so its link count is now 2. If a `"/a/b/c"` directory is created, because of the `".."` entry in `"/a/b/c"`, the link count of `"/a/b"` will become 3.

Most Unices restrict creating further links to a directory because they can cause problematic loops. When they do allow a `link()` on a directory, generally only the superuser can do it.

Some filesystems like `btrfs` depart from that traditional directory structure. You'll notice that link counts on directories in `btrfs` file systems are always one even though those directories do contain a `"."` entry with the same inode number as themselves in them.

The fact that the link count is traditionally 2 plus the number of subdirs has its use. For instance, in:

```
find . -name '*.c' -print
```

if `.` does not contain subdirs but contains millions of files. By checking the link count of `.`, `find` can know that there is no subdir. So all `find` has to do is read the content of the directory and report the entries that end in `.c` (like a `grep '\.c$'` on a few megabyte file, no big deal). Otherwise, `find` would have to check the type of every single file to see if there are directories to descend into in there (resulting in as many `lstat()` system calls). Of course, this kind of optimisation doesn't work on `btrfs` (though in modern versions of Linux, the type of files is also stored in the directory entry for some filesystems (including `btrfs`) and returned by the `getdents(2)` system call used to retrieve the list of entries in a directory, so `lstat` is still not necessary).

Comment: You compare a Unix directory to a telephone directory.  I guess that’s a valid comparison, but when I think “telephone directory”, I think of a book that’s bigger than just about any other book I’ve ever seen — bigger than *any* book I’ve seen in the past ten years — that lists all the people and businesses in a region of two or three counties.  A telephone directory might have over a million entries, and you probably wouldn’t have more than two or three of them in your house.  A telephone directory is, in some respects, more like the i-list than an individual directory. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … The phone tree at a company might be a better analogy.  The president might have a Rolodex listing the CEO, the COO, the CFO, the CIO, and nobody else.  The CEO might have a Rolodex listing the Director of Research and a few other people.  The CFO might have a Rolodex listing the Director of Marketing and a few other people.  If you wanted to talk to John Smith, who works on an assembly line or in a cubicle farm, you might (in principle) have to go through the president, the COO, the plant manager, the shift supervisor, and John’s immediate supervisor — in order to get John’s phone.