# What's the second column of ls -l say?

Tags: linux, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the number between file permission and owner in ls -l command output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/what-is-the-number-between-file-permission-and-owner-in-ls-l-command-output)

I've been using Linux for years now and I'm embarrassed to say that until now I didn't notice that I have no idea what the second column of `ls -l` means:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 roic develop1 roic  685 2012-10-11 14:15 API.h
           ^
```

In this example - 1. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the no. of the links that the file is having...links is the nothing but different names of the same file

Links are of two type hard and soft links

use the following code:

```
    ln file1 file2 #ln command creates file2 as a link of file 1
    ls -l file1
```

This will show 2 in place of 1 bcoz file1 has two names
Now file1 and file2
Now same file can be used by two different names

Arun

Comment: As manatwork's linked answer points out, it is the number of _hard_ links only. Soft links don't affect this refcount.

Comment: But make sure that file2 is not already created while using the above code..thnx

Comment: ya you are ryt....soft link doesnt affect refcount. @useless