# What does the second field of ls -l represent for directories?

Tags: linux, ls

I'd like to ask some help with a question about "ls" program: could please anyone explain what does the second field of "ls -l" output mean?

Here is an example:

```
sergey@home-ubuntu:~$ ls -l
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  8 sergey sergey  4096 мая 12 11:54 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  5 sergey sergey  4096 апр 28 00:09 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 10 sergey sergey 12288 мая 12 23:22 Downloads
drwxrwxr-x  3 sergey sergey  4096 апр 12 15:22 Games
drwxrwxr-x  7 sergey sergey  4096 апр  2 23:02 MEGAsync
drwxr-xr-x  3 sergey sergey  4096 апр 15 21:18 Music
drwxr-xr-x  4 sergey sergey  4096 мая  7 09:10 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 sergey sergey  4096 апр  2 22:24 Public
drwxrwxr-x  4 sergey sergey  4096 апр  9 17:57 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x  5 sergey sergey  4096 апр 16 22:42 snap
drwxrwxr-x  3 sergey sergey  4096 мая  9 21:20 Soft
drwxr-xr-x  2 sergey sergey  4096 апр  2 22:24 Templates
drwxrwxr-x  3 sergey sergey  4096 мая 12 23:39 Tests
drwxr-xr-x  3 sergey sergey  4096 мая 12 16:11 Videos
            ^
         this field i'm interested in
```

The [internet says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54984/whats-the-second-column-of-ls-l-say) it shows the number of links to a *file*, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) specifies to hard links, but i couldn't find any information about directories, yet it's represented in ls -l output.

Since one can't create a hard link to a folder, it's unclear what that field means.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/what-is-the-number-between-file-permission-and-owner-in-ls-l-command-output help? ("the number of contained directory entries, when referring to a directory.")

Comment: @JeffSchaller, i'm a little too late with my answer, but yes, your link does help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `info ls`:

> ‘-l’
>   ‘--format=long’
>   ‘--format=verbose’
>   In addition to the name of each file, print the file type, file mode bits, **number of hard links**, owner name, group name, size, and timestamp (*note Formatting file timestamps::), normally the modification timestamp (the mtime, *note File timestamps::).  Print question marks for information that cannot be determined.

So, yes, that is the number of hard links.But what does it mean?

Simple: quite similar to the number of files in the directory.

At the start, when a directory is created, it starts with two hard links (think of that as the hard links for `.` and `..`)

```
$ mkdir anewone
$ ls -lad anewone
drwxr-xr-x 2 isaac isaac 4096 May 12 18:29 anewone
...........^^..... 2 hard links.
```

As you create new **sub-directories** in that directory, the number of hard links increase:

```
$ touch anewone/{a..e}
$ ls -lad anewone
drwxr-xr-x 2 isaac isaac 4096 May 12 18:30 anewone
...........^^..... No change for files.

$ mkdir anewone/{f..m}
$ ls -lad anewone
drwxr-xr-x 10 isaac isaac 4096 May 12 18:30 anewone
...........^^..... 8 new directories ==> 10 hard links.
```

Related:

[Why does a new directory have a hard link count of 2 before anything is added to it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515/why-does-a-new-directory-have-a-hard-link-count-of-2-before-anything-is-added-to)

[hardlink count for directory](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hardlink-count-for-directory-4175554878/)

Comment: Thank you! Never thought that these ".." are actually hard links.