# How can I delete a hardlink to a directory?

Tags: linux, directory, hard-link

Before I get 100s of answers that tell me it is impossible to hardlink directories in linux: yes, I know that.

The file in question appeared in lost+fount after I checked the filesystem with `e2fsck` (its an ext4) and according to stat it /is/ a file with 2 hardlinks:

```
# stat --format="File \"%n\" is a %F with %h hardlinks" ./#30934353
File "./#30934353" is a directory with 2 hardlinks
```

Doh. How can I safely delete them without touching the included files? I tried `rm` and `unlink`, both told me that die directory is not empty…

Comment: A directory with a link count of 2 is a perfectly normal and healthy directory (e.g. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31073/how-to-find-all-the-links-to-a-directory)). Do you really have a problem?

Comment: You are right, thank you! I completely misunderstood the output of e2fsck and stat. I just "rm -R"ed the directories and all is fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directories on ext4 file systems generally have at least 2 links. The entry in their parent directory and the `.` entry in themselves. See [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75493/22565) for more details.

Having said that, if the file system is inconsistent, you may very well have a directory linked in more than one place and the link count not to reflect it.

For instance, with `debugfs -w` (on an unmounted fs), you can do `link a/b c/d` to force the creation of a link to a directory. You'll notice that the link count is not updated (you'd need `sif a/b links_count 3` to update it):

```
$ ls -lid a/b c/d a/b/. c/d/.
12 drwxr-xr-x 2 chazelas chazelas 1024 May 14 08:37 a/b/
12 drwxr-xr-x 2 chazelas chazelas 1024 May 14 08:37 a/b/./
12 drwxr-xr-x 2 chazelas chazelas 1024 May 14 08:37 c/d/
12 drwxr-xr-x 2 chazelas chazelas 1024 May 14 08:37 c/d/./
```

The link count is 2 above, even though there are 3 links (to a, to c, and the "." to itself).

Note that `fsck` would report a problem with that:

```
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'd' in /c (1282) is a link to directory /a/b (12).
Clear<y>?
```

So it's unlikely to be your case here if the fs has just gone through a fsck.

To remove one of those links, you can use `debugfs -w` again (after having unmounted the filesystem) and do `unlink c/d` in it, or use `fsck`. If a `directory` has more than one link, you can check the `..` entry within it (with `debugfs` `ls`) to check which is the correct one (`..` will have the same inode number as its correct parent).